# Due date calculate based on the user input and start date in datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

Hi i and to calculate the end date based on the user input and the start date

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Months</label>
    <input type="text" name="chit_months" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Start Date</label>
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" name="start_date" id="example1" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#example1').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    });

    $('#example2').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    });
</script>
```

I am using the datepicker, if the user enter the month in text box and  he select the start date, The end date should automatically calculate by the jQuery

Please help me to know how to do this.

Comment: You need to share your code also - your html and script that you have tried

Comment: sorry i added arun my html code now.

Answer (score 0):

below code give you difference between two date beyond that you can calculate your due amount

```
function getDueDays(){
   var sdate = new Date($('#startDate').val());
   var month = new Date($('#month').val());
   Date dd= new Date(new Date(sdate).setMonth(sdate.getMonth()+month));
   $('#endDate').val(dd);  
}
```

Comment: hi vishnu thank you for the reply. actually the user enter the month in the text box above in the start date after he select the start date from the date picker the end date should be automatically calculate and also the End date box is read only. This all process are have to do before submit

Comment: the datepicker is not working now vishnu i add the script                  function getDueDays(){
 $('#example1').datepicker({
         format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
     }); 
 $('#example2').datepicker({
         format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
     });
   var sdate = new Date($('#example1').val());
   var month = new Date($('#month').val());
   Date dd= new Date(new Date(sdate).setMonth(sdate.getMonth()+month));
   $('#example2').val(dd);  
}

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#example1').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
  });

  $('#example2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
  });

  $('#chit_months, #example1').change(function() {
    var months = +$('#chit_months').val() || 0,
      date = $('#example1').datepicker('getDate');
    if (months && date) {
      date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months);
      $('#example2').datepicker('setDate', date);
    } else {
      $('#example2').val('');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="form-group">
  <label>Months</label>
  <input type="text" id="chit_months" name="chit_months" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Start Date</label>
  <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="start_date" id="example1" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>End Date</label>
  <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="start_date" id="example2" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's Working perfect arun

Comment: arun i have an another doubt the date format is dd/mm/yyyy but it showing  month/date/year how can i change that